# Merging two queues in alphabetic orders

Tags: python, queue

I'm trying to merge two queues (these two queues assume that have been alphabetically sorted) into a third queue and return the third queue in alphabetical order. For example:

```
queue1 = ["a","d","x"]
queue2 = ["b","c","y","z"]
# the third queue should look like
queue3 = ["a","b","c","d","x","y","z"]
```

This is my code (I'm doing without using the method `merge()`):

```
import string
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack

class Stack1Queue:

  Stackone = Stack()
  Stackto = Stack()

def __init__(self):
  self.items = []

def add(self, element):
  self.items.append(element)

def remove(self):
  if len(Stackto) == 0:
      if len(Stackone) == 0:
          return None
      while not Stackone.isEmpty():
          p = Stackone.pop()
          Stackto.push(p)
   return Stackto.pop()

def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

def isEmpty(self):
    return self.items == []

def size(self):
    return len(self.items)


class MergeQueue(Stack1Queue):
  adict = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))
  Queuethr = Stack()

  def merge(self, Stackone, Stackto):

      while not Stackone.isEmpty() and Stackto.isEmpty():
          for k, v in adict.items():
              if Stackone.peek() == adict.get(v):
                  Queuethr.push(Stackone.peek())
              else:
                  Queuethr.push(Stackto.peek())
          print(dict(Queuethr))
          return 1
```

Basically my first class `Stack1Queue`is to implements two stack to create a queue. Anyway, I just wonder whether my `merge` function is correctly written or not. When I try to run:

```
s = Stack1Queue()
p = Stack1Queue()
q = MergeQueue()
s.add("z")
s.add("y")
s.add("d")
s.add("b")
s.add("a")
p.add("x")
p.add("d")
p.add("c")
print(q.merge(s, p))
```

It return 0 for the size of `q`

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. If you want feedback on your implementation, formulate your subject and body to reflect that. If you want to know how to merge and then sort two lists, please remove the code as it does not really clarify your question. It seems vash has you covered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate and use `sorted`

```
queue1 = ["a","d","x"]
queue2 = ["b","c","y","z"]

queue3 = sorted(queue1 + queue2)
```

> ```
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'y', 'z']
> ```

Comment: Python's queues don't actually do that, even if OP's code does have lists instead of queues. Should the question be edited?